# JSON get with angular and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I wanted to ask you a little help . When I try to communicate my front end in angular with the part of the back end ( php ) on the console as soon as I left the service I get an empty array

Controller:

```
angular.module('pageModule')
.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'homeService', 'pageService', function($scope, homeService, pageService){

  $scope.pages = new Array();

  pageService.getPage().then(function(response){
    var elenco = response.data;
    console.log(elenco);
    for(var i = 0; i < elenco.length; i++)
      $scope.pages.push(elenco[i]);
  });
  console.log($scope.pages);
}]);
```

This is the service:

```
angular.module('pageModule')
.service('pageService', function($http){
  function getPage(){
    return $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/page.php');
  }
  return{
    getPage: getPage
  };
});
```

And this is the PHP part:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/class.core.php';
$page = new angCMS(); //this function connected the DB
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($page->getPage());
}

 ?>
```

In the console:
﻿

```
pageModuleController.js:12 []
pageModuleController.js:8 Object {id: "1", title: "prova", content: "prova"}
﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

As far angular is concerned include the console.log statement inside the .then callback. Because it looses its scope when the .then callback function ends.

```
 angular.module('pageModule')
    .controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'homeService', 'pageService', function($scope, homeService, pageService){

      $scope.pages = new Array();

      pageService.getPage().then(function(response){
        var elenco = response.data;
        console.log(elenco);
        for(var i = 0; i < elenco.length; i++){
          $scope.pages.push(elenco[i]);
}
console.log($scope.pages);
      });

    }]);
```

Comment: but this way the ng - repeat = "pages in page " is not working , how do I fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Is nothing wrong with your code. $http.get is always executed async. This is way you have an empty array on last line in the service. After $http retrieves the php page response, will call your function in .then(...) and feds $scope.pages

Comment: but this way the ng - repeat = "pages in page " is not working , how do I fix ?