# AngularJS and PHP Communication service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Why in this code -> [JSON get with angular and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887436/json-get-with-angular-and-php/) , the service return an empty array but if i write:

```
angular.module('pageModule')
.factory('pageService', function($http){
  var pagesArray =  new Array();

  return{
    pagesArray: pagesArray,

    load: function(){
      $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/page.php')
      .success(function(res){
        pagesArray.push(res);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('pageModule')
.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'homeService', 'pageService', function($scope, homeService, pageService){

  $scope.pages = pageService.pagesArray;

  pageService.load();

}]);
```

everything works great?

Comment: Please read [ask] and be more specific about what your issue is. It's not at all clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not waiting for the call to be made. Make use of the promise that the $http is returning.

Factory:

```
// Original
angular.module('pageModule')
.factory('pageService', function($http){
  var pagesArray =  new Array();

  return{
    pagesArray: pagesArray,

    load: function(){
      $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/page.php')
      // Success is deprecated use then and catch
      .success(function(res){
        pagesArray.push(res);
      });
    }
  };
});

// Changed
angular.module('pageModule')
.factory('pageService', function($http){
  var pagesArray =  new Array();

  return{
    pagesArray: pagesArray,

    load: function(){
      return $http.get('../angCMS/server/php/page.php')
      .then(function(res){
        pagesArray.push(res); 
        return pagesArray;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
//Original
angular.module('pageModule')
.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'homeService', 'pageService', function($scope, homeService, pageService){

  $scope.pages = pageService.pagesArray;

  pageService.load();

}]);

//Changed
angular.module('pageModule')
.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'homeService', 'pageService', function($scope, homeService, pageService){

  $scope.pages = [] //Initiale state;

  //Make use of the HTTP promise that is returned in the load
  pageService.load()
    .then(function (pages) {
      $scope.pages = pages;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      //Handle error
      console.log(error);
    });

}]);
```